# IIS 7 - Single Page Application URL issues when aliased

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc

A client of ours has the following setup under IIS

```
Sites
 - applications (binds to http://applications.domain.com)
  - app1
  - app2
```

`app1` and `app2` are both .NET Single Page Applications (combination of .NET MVC and .NET Web API).

The applications are under the `C:\inetpub\applications\` folder and both have been converted to applications. Thus *app1* is available under the following URL `http://applications.domain.com/app1` and *app2* is available under `http://applications.domain.com/app2`

The problem I'm running into is that all the AJAX routes are relative to the root (/) route and are therefore non existant e.g. `http://applications.domain.com/api/products` doesn't throws a 404 since the route is actually `http://applications.domain.com/app1/api/products`.

Is there an IIS setting that will allow me to make this work short of re-writing all my AJAX calls with the prefix? Or is there a different way I can configure this kind of setup under IIS? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is put both apps in their own virtual directories -- then most of the asp.net calls will get the correct document root and things will be righter with the world.

To do so:

1. make a fake document root and fake website -- iis7 needs someplace to stash a web.config file and this should be unique to this app. I'd use something like c:\inetpub\applications\deadroot; add an IIS site looking at this folder.
2. Add a virtual application for app1 pointed at app1's folder inside this site
3. Add a virtual application for app2 pointed at app2's folder inside this site

Each will then stand on it's head.

Comment: Could you please provide more detail on points 1 and 2? I'm not sure what you mean by fake document root and standing a website. For points 3 and 4, do I add these as applications or virtual directories? Thanks.

Comment: Fleshed it out a bit but you want apps not virtual directories here.